# Replace zero values with last available value in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, left-join, gaps-and-islands

[SQL-FIDDLE Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf5d7/1)

I'm using SQL Server.

Edit: Used a wrong SQL Fiddle before - updated to correct one

The join statement:

```
select t1.A_NR, t1.V_DATE, t1.AMOUNT T1_AMOUNT, t2.AMOUNT T2_AMOUNT
from Table_1 t1 
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.A_NR = t2.A_NR and t1.V_DATE = t2.V_DATE
```

brings me this table with null values in the T2_Amount row.

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| A_NR |        V_DATE        | T1_AMOUNT | T2_AMOUNT |
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z |       100 | 100       |
|    1 | 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z |       101 | (null)    |
|    1 | 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z |       102 | (null)    |
|    2 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z |       200 | 200       |
|    2 | 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z |       201 | (null)    |
|    2 | 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z |       202 | (null)    |
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to replace these values with the last available values from Table_2 like this:

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| A_NR |        V_DATE        | T1_AMOUNT | T2_AMOUNT |
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z |       100 |       100 |
|    1 | 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z |       101 |       100 | -->  value from 01.01.2020
|    1 | 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z |       102 |       100 | -->  value from 01.01.2020
|    2 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z |       200 |       200 |
|    2 | 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z |       201 |       200 | -->  value from 01.01.2020
|    2 | 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z |       202 |       200 | -->  value from 01.01.2020
+------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: *"I'm using MSSQL."* then why is your SQL Fiddle clearly MySQL?

Comment: trying to change that rigth now, didnt see that while creating the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery, or a lateral join:

```
select t1.a_nr, t1.v_date, t1.amount as t1_amount, t2.* 
from table_1 t1 
outer apply (
    select top (1) t2.amount as t2_amount
    from table_2 t2 
    where t2.a_nr = t1.a_nr and t2.v_date <= t1.v_date
    order by t2.v_date desc
) t2
```

An alternative is to use some gaps-and-island technique: we can put unmatched records in groups along with the latest matched record with a window count, then use a window max to recover the value we want:

```
select a_nr, v_date, amount as t1_amount, 
    max(t2_amount) over(partition by a_nr, grp)
from (
    select t1.*, t2.amount as t2_amount,
        count(t2.amount) over(partition by t1.a_nr order by t1.v_date) as grp
    from table_1 t1 
    left join table_2 t2 on t2.a_nr = t1.a_nr and t2.v_date = t1.v_date
) t
```

Comment: hi thanks for the fast reply that command raises an sql syntax error in the sql fiddle

Comment: The Outer apply raises this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer apply ( select top (1) t2.amount as t2_amount from table_2 t2 ' at line 3

Comment: @PeterS: this is a MySQL error, while you explained you are running SQL Server (and tagged accordingly).

Comment: `order t2.v_date desc` should be `order BY t2.v_date desc` @GMB . Otherwise your answer parses fine.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Fixed.

Comment: sorry.. i mwrongly created the fiddle in mysql

Comment: If you *are* using SQL Server (as you tag and say in the question) and not MySQL (as the fiddle suggests) this works fine, @PeterS : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae3d7abec7f84636d8ea841afa0183cf)

Comment: once again.. sorry.. new to sql fiddle... thanks everything works perfect